# Changing and nerfing my backstory and class

Tags: problem-gm

My GM has changed my backstory repeatedly, to the point where I’m not even sure what it is completely anymore, and then let everyone else in the group be what they wanted. So now we have:

- a very powerful noble,
- a werewolf who it has been confirmed will not die unless the enemies are using silver weapons (all the enemies we have faced so far have not had said weapons),
- and me.

And then he changed me from being a spy to something, and when he realized I was still being sneaky (I’m playing a rogue), he said a ring appeared one day as if sent from god (religious character) and it was when we really needed a certain item. So he lets me put it on after we had it inspected, and he tells me a blinding light is glowing from the ring with no way to shut it off or cover it up. So now I can’t sneak cause I’m like a walking sun if I’m in the shadows (there is no other upside to the ring besides the bright light which for my character isn’t a upside).

Meanwhile he has also nerfed multiple things in my class such as sneak attack damage, how many proficiencies I get from being a rogue, among other things.

I really enjoy playing with them but I don’t really want to continue with this character or have him step into me making a new character. I made sure my class and backstory before he changed them were okay to use and he said they were fine.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. I see you've already taken the [tour] so I suggest checking out the [help] as well to get more of an idea of what this site is about. Most importantly is that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Questions here must contain, well, an actual question. What's the actual question you're asking here? At the moment this reads a lot more like a rant. We need the post to be clear and concise so could you please revise and [edit] it with proper punctuation and paragraphs with clear details about what the problem and question is? Also please include the game you're playing.

Comment: Possibly related: [Should I continue to play with a frustrating DM?](/questions/170958/), [How to communicate to my GM that not being allowed to use stealth isn't fun for me?](/questions/149331/)

Comment: I've given the question a once-over with punctuation and linebreaks to improve its readability, but I'm going to echo the others; what is your question here?